# How can I count each dictionary value output in Python in the following code example?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning to play with lists, tuples and dictionaries in Python (2.7), and to convert dictionaries to lists and to reference them, but am experiencing some difficulties in understanding how I might add a count number to specific values that I am retrieving from dictionaries.

I start with this code as follows:

```
users = {
    'Participants': [ 
        {'first_name':  'Jerry', 'last_name' : 'Johnson'},
        {'first_name' : 'Blaine', 'last_name' : 'Diamond'},
        {'first_name' : 'Ginny', 'last_name' : 'Gelspy'},
        {'first_name' : 'LG', 'last_name' : 'Murphy'}
     ],
    'Leaders': [
        {'first_name' : 'TJ', 'last_name' : 'Knight'},
        {'first_name' : 'Jasper', 'last_name' : 'Red'}
     ]
}

users_list = users.items()  # converts users dict to a list
for key, data in users_list: 
    print key
    for value in data:
        print "-", value["first_name"].upper(), value["last_name"].upper(), "-", len(value["first_name"] + value["last_name"])
```

My current output is as follows:

```
Participants
- JERRY JOHNSON - 12
- BLAINE DIAMOND - 13
- GINNY GELSPY - 11
- LG MURPHY - 8
Leaders
- TJ KNIGHT - 8
- JASPER RED - 9
```

However, I'd like to add a count to each participant or leader, so the output would instead read:

```
Participants
1 - JERRY JOHNSON - 12
2 - BLAINE DIAMOND - 13
3 - GINNY GELSPY - 11
4 - LG MURPHY - 8
Leaders
1 - TJ KNIGHT - 8
2 - JASPER RED - 9
```

in this format:

```
<dictionary name>
<count> - <FULL NAME IN CAPS> - <char count in full name no space included>
```

I did read that dictionaries in python are unordered and cannot be referenced in regards to index, but is there a simple way to setup a counter or to count each output in a way that I'm not seeing?

Thank you so much for any insight provided!

Comment: Take a look at [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: BTW, if you're just starting to learn Python now you probably should be learning Python 3 unless you have a _really_ good reason forcing you to use Python 2.

Comment: @PM 2Ring - Thanks for the suggestion to use 'enumerate', I did attempt this previously but my syntax was wrong and all of the posters here helped clarify! I was condoned to start in 2.7.12 as I was told that Python 3 is not used as frequently as 2.7.x versions -- aka, as a developer I'll hit Python 2.x examples more than 3.0 but perhaps this is where theory v. actuality in life may differ ... (again, I am learning so this was suggested by the developers teaching me but open to other lines of reasoning) ... Thank you so much!

Comment: With all due respect, your teachers' advice is a little out of date. Several years ago it _was_ common to recommend Py 2 over Py 3, but that's no longer the case. Back then, many important 3rd party Python libraries didn't support Py 3, but now the vast majority of Python libraries do have Py 3 versions. Also, the core Py 3 language itself has improved in various ways.

Comment: (cont)  Yes, there is still a _huge_ Py 2 code base, and if you need to maintain old code you _will_ need to learn Py 2, but it's not that hard to pick up Py 2 if you already know Py 3; going the other direction is a little harder, but it's not a huge deal if you have a good grasp of the way Python does stuff. Py 2 is being phased out: the official maintainers of the standard Python interpreter (CPython) originally announced that they were dropping Py 2 support in 2015, they extended the date to 2020 after protests from the user base.

Comment: (cont) However, nothing new has been added in recent years to Python 2.7, only bug fixes & security updates. FWIW, The [Stack Overflow Python Community](http://sopython.com) recommends Python 3 for all new Python projects, and to all new Python learners. Also see [Python 3 Statement](https://python3statement.github.io).

Comment: @PM 2Ring This is definitely very interesting and valid information! Thanks for being so thorough here in explaining the response from the community and the official Python 3 statement. I may have to ask my instructors about this for sure...it does seem odd to learn a bunch of functions that may be improved in later versions of the language...As I get my head above water with these concepts, I'll take your notes into consideration and start working into Python 3 on my own...thanks to this community for all the insight and straight forward wisdom :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for key, data in users_list: 
    print key
    for count, value in enumerate(data):
        print (count + 1), "-", value["first_name"].upper(), value["last_name"].upper(), "-", len(value["first_name"] + value["last_name"])
```

That should do it. Read more about `enumerate` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, you can also do `enumerate(data, start=1)` instead. You wouldn't need `count + 1` in that case:

```
for key, data in users_list: 
    print key
    for count, value in enumerate(data, start=1):
        print count, "-", value["first_name"].upper(), value["last_name"].upper(), "-", len(value["first_name"] + value["last_name"])
```

Comment: You don't need `count+1`. Pass enumerate a `start` arg of 1.

Comment: @Priyatham  - this was really helpful and I greatly appreciate your response here! I was able to enumerate(data) and now am receiving the count!

Comment: @PM 2Ring, could you provide an example of how to use enumerate with a start argument? The syntax of python for loops in this manner (compared to javascript) is throwing me for a loop at times (no pun intended)! Copious thanks for all of your help and insight!

Comment: @timothy-knab I added a snippet with start argument in my edit.

Comment: @Priyatham - This works perfectly! Thank you so much for your quick response and for your cont'd help! Made a big difference here!

Comment: @timothy-knab: I see that Priyatham has added a new example, so I won't bother writing one. BTW that `enumerate` call can be simplified to `enumerate(data, 1)`. OTOH, explicitly mentioning the `start` keyword makes the code more readable. Yes, Python `for` loops are a little bit different to JavaScript's, but I'm sure that with more practice you'll come to agree that the Python way is more powerful, and more sensible. :)

Answer (score 0):

Start the counter to 0 right after the first for loop, and increase by 1 each time after the second for loop:

```
for key, data in users_list: 
    counter = 0
    print key
    for value in data:
        counter += 1
        print str(counter), "-", value["first_name"].upper(), value["last_name"].upper(), "-", len(value["first_name"] + value["last_name"])
```

Comment: Thank you for contribution and for your help! I did try this method as outline (not using enumerate) but creating the counter variable. I actually tried this solution before posting here but receive an error when building, in regards to the declaration of the counter variable as follows: 
`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: @timothy-knab that was most likely that you mix together spaces and tab without notice it, change all the tab for spaces and configure your editor to do and you will never find that error again

Comment: I'm glad you learned how to use the `enumerate` function, and to apply it in this case. However, this very simple pattern of initializing a variable outside of the loop and change it inside the loop, is very common and should be one pattern to keep in your programming toolkit. You can calculate min, max, count, sum, or change the variables only if some condition is met. Consider it again and make it work. It will prove useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the *enumerate* function on the list like that:

```
users_list = users.items()  # converts users dict to a list
for key, data in users_list:
print key
for i, value in enumerate(data, 1):
    print str(i), "-", value["first_name"].upper(), value["last_name"].upper(), "-", len(value["first_name"] + value["last_name"])
```

The *enumerate* function returns the index in addition to the element itself.

EDIT:

As mentioned in Priyatham Kattakinda's answer, the second parameter of the function indicates the first element's index (the default is zero).

Comment: you don't need to explicitly convert `i` to a string, `print` do it for you

Comment: @AvielNiego  - thanks so much for this insight also. Thanks for helping clarify what exactly enumerate is doing. It does appears that 'count' or 'i' gives us the index value. Is there a fundamental difference between 'count' and 'i'? When using 'i' I did also have to print 'i + 1' just so that the index count officially starts at 1 (a requirement of the desired program output). Thanks for your keen insight!

Comment: @Copperfield Thanks for this insight as well. Int values work just fine in this case!

Comment: @timothy-knab `enumerate` give a tuples containing a number a whatever value is inside of what you give to it, you can call that number whatever you like `i`, `count`, `j`, etc when used as `for i, value in enumerate(something)`. It have a optional second argument which tell where to start counting, if omitted it default to 0. so for example `enumerate(["a","b"])`result in `(0,"a"), (0,"b")`, and `enumerate(["a","b"],n)` result in `(n,"a"), (n+1,"b")` for all n

Comment: @timothy-knab in resume enumerate do for you what chapelo is doing in his answer with counter

Comment: @Copperfield thanks so much for taking the time to explain this so throughly. I like that python has its own unique ways of doing things and I think as I keep practicing I'll keep building familiarity and deeper understanding...at first some of these concepts are foreign to my thinking, but with more and more practice their intention and proper use becomes clear...thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

as mention by other, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is the best way to go, so I will just add some extra tip to make the program more efficient:

1. unless you really need the `user_list` later on, iterate over `users.items()` directly or better yet as you are in python 2, iterate over `users.iteritems()` the reason is that [`.items`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) make a copy of the whole thing which is a waste of space and time, while [`.iteritems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) don't do that. In python 3 `items` is equivalent to `iteritems`. In this little program that might not have a significant impact, but if the dictionary were much larger you would notice a difference
2. and speaking of wasted space, here `len(value["first_name"] + value["last_name"])` you are making a new string, without any other change, to just calculate its length so you're wasting a little bit of space here, so just add the length of each

with those tip the changes are a follow

```
for key, data in users.iteritems(): 
    print key
    for i, value in enumerate(data, 1):
        print i, "-", value["first_name"].upper(), value["last_name"].upper(), "-", len(value["first_name"]) + len(value["last_name"])
```

You can take a look at [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) [formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) to have a better control over how it will look like, for instance with string formatting this can be done as

```
print "{} - {} {} - {}".format(i, value["last_name"].upper(), value["last_name"].upper(), len(value["first_name"]) + len(value["last_name"]) )
```

(for more interesting examples look at the documentation)

Comment: very helpful, thanks so much for helping me refactor my code a bit as well to waste less space. I probably didn't have to setup "users_list" but was trying to mess around with the dictionary once in "list" format (as I was trying to claw my way towards a solutIon) but since probably is unnecessary. Thanks so much for your insight and solutions!